# How to pass the values to bootstrap modal window and show the dynamic content

Tags: coldfusion, bootstrap-4, coldfusion-10

I need to pass the userName to the bootstrap modal window and show the passing name in modal window.

For example,

If i pass jawa the modal will show the content like 'This is jawa'

Answer (score 2):

we need to add the attirbute data-id the in your button like as below,

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="##myModal" data-id="jawa">Delete</button>
```

This JS function will be called before open boostrap modal window. And in that function we can able to get the data-id attribute value and then we can able to write a code based on getting value. See the below code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        var userName = $(event.relatedTarget).data('id');
        $("#modalText").html("You are going to be deleted" + userName);
    });
</script>
```

This is the modal window code,

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">   
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="cancelModal">Google Map</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="modalText"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="" target="_blank" id="mapLink">Open in new tab</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Of course the content of you modal would be more closing related to deleting operation.